# How do you setup static paths in javascript?

Tags: javascript, path, reactjs

This may be a silly question, but I can't seem to find a simple answer via google

Lets say I have a react component library, full of display component, and I want it to be easily included into most of my smart/container components. Because it will be used all over the place, I'd rather not use relative paths from every different component in my app `import Component from '../../library/Component'` and `../library/Component` and `../../../library/Component` etc...

How could I set it up so all I had to do was `import Component from 'library/Component'` wherever in the app I wanted to be?

Asked another way, what is the generally prescribed way to setup static paths in javascript?

Comment: Which build system are you using? Webpack or browserify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) you could using way of "several root directories". Builder will find your modules by several paths. And you can write something like this: "./lodash" instead "../../../../lodash". Look [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories) for more info.

Comment: If you specify a `reoslve.root`, the path is no longer relative at all. E.g. `root: [ path.resolve( './path/to/my/code' ) ]` will allow you to require a file in that `code` folder by just asking for it: `require( 'mymodule' )` would translate to requiring the `./path/to/my/code/mymodule.js`.

Comment: I'm using webpack and this got it to work. I did have to use two separate root paths `root: path.resolve('./shared-components')` and `root: path.resolve('./')` Is this a good idea or is there a better way? Like with `resolve.modulesDirectories()`?

Comment: resolve.root more special than resolve.modulesDirectories. Because second is using [node's resolving algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders). But in your case you can use both variants.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your scripts are located off the base path, why not begin the paths with "/" so you don't have to deal with all the ../../../ etc.

I've created virtual directories to make it possible for me to use /library/Component/etc.

On some systems you can't do it this way so you have to use something like ${system_root}/path/to/component